# du -- ignore file not found errors

Tags: disk-usage

I'm trying to get the size of a folder an application is currently writing to. If I run the `du` command it sometimes fails with the error:

```
du: cannot access `/a/b/a.txt': No such file or directory
```

because the application deleted the file while `du` was processing. How can I tell it to ignore such errors?

Answer (score 8):

You can filter standard error using `grep`, without losing (possibly important) other error messages. In `bash`:

```
du 2> >(grep -v '^du: cannot \(access\|read\)' >&2)
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
     du -sh /home/dir 2> /dev/null | cut -f1
```